# Line breaks in paragraphed footnotes in reledmac

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

`reledmac`'s paragraphed footnotes cannot contain explicit line breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{Something}{\Afootnote{else.}}. 
And \edtext{something more}{\Afootnote{Something\\
with\\ some\\ linebreaks.}}. 
And \edtext{a last footnote}{\Afootnote{Done.}}.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

produces the following:

[image]

Only the last line of the second footnote is printed, without xelatex giving any error or warning.

This is also discussed (p.153f., in `\paravfootnote`) in the documentation, where for a possible workaround Michael Downes's ‘Line Breaking in \unhboxed Text’, TUGboat 11 (1990), pp. 605–612 is referred to. I've provisionally tried replacing `\\` with `\penalty-9999`, which did print out the whole second footnote, however without the desired linebreaks. For me the main application of this would be in using the verse environment in a paragraphed footnote, how can it be done?

Comment: I have no idea, and no time to look on this complex feature. I have thought about it since 3 years, and not any serious pist…